# How to create an Angular 2 directive to parse hashtags and create a click event?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 (Angular 2) app that has a div with text that may include hashtags.  I need to create a directive that parses the text and for each hashtag replaces it with a span with a class and a click event:

```
    <div>I am a post that includes #hashtag1 and #hashtag2<div>
```

Should become:

```
    <div>I am a post that includes 
      <span class="hashtag" (click)="gotoHashtag('hashtag1')>#hashtag1</span> 
      and 
      <span class="hashtag" (click)="gotoHashtag('hashtag2')>#hashtag2</span>
    </div>
```

In my Ionic 1 app (angular 1) I used the angular-hashtagify directive: https://github.com/rossmartin/angular-hashtagify

I am trying to make a angular 2 version of this for my Ionic 2 app. So far I have:

```
import {Directive,ElementRef,Renderer} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HashtagPage} from '../pages/hashtag/hashtag';

@Directive({
    selector:'[hashtagify]'
})
export class HashtagifyDirective{

constructor(private el:ElementRef, private render:Renderer, public navCtrl: NavController){
}

private addHashtag() {
    setTimeout(()=> {
       let content = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
       let newcontent = content.replace(/(^|\s)*#(\w+)/g, '$1<span class="hashtag">#$2</span>');
        this.render.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', newcontent);
        this.render.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            let hashtag = event.target.innerText;
            this.navCtrl.push(HashtagPage, {'hashtagTitle': hashtag.substring(1, hashtag.length)});
         });
     },1);
}

     ngOnInit(){
        this.addHashtag();
     }
}
```

This code correctly styles the hashtag, but it places the click event on the div rather than the span.  I just need a little help placing the click event on each of the spans that holds a formatted hashtag.  My guess is that I have to use the renderer's addElement function for each span and then add a click event to that new element, but I am not sure how. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: can you have a plunker for the same ?

Comment: thanks for trying to help in advance. Its my first time trying to set up a plunkr but here it is:  https://plnkr.co/edit/rxr51icHWP8vuY11rQZ8?p=preview for some reason the directive is not working at all on the plunker. I am not sure why.

Comment: The directive is not working in plunker i guess it is due to the external scripts that is not loading in plunker can you check

Comment: I am not good at ionic if you can try and make the directive work in the plunjker, the diective is not getting called in the plunker i checked

Comment: there is app module also in the plunker

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh. I will try to fix it. I know Ionic but I dont know plunker :( Is there any console in plunker?

Comment: Sry man couldn't help much . U need to check or like team viewer or smthng

Comment: Ok here it is:  http://plnkr.co/edit/g2uNJJawhkN9B9h2C2V6?p=preview .   As you can see, clicking on #hashtag1 works as does clicking on #hashtag2.  If you click on the card item (outside #hashtag1 or #hashtag2) it still uses the click event, when it shouldn't.

Comment: will check it man let me have my dinner first : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what is that you wanted

Chnaged the add HashTag method click event listner

```
private addHashtag() {
          setTimeout(()=> {

        let content = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;

        let newcontent = content.replace(/(^|\s)*#(\w+)/g, '$1<span class="hashtagColored">#$2</span>');
            this.render.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', newcontent);
            this.render.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => 
            if(event.srcElement.classList.contains('hashtagColored')){
              console.log(); // this is the if that checks the class
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                let hashtag = event.target.innerText;
                this.navCtrl.push(Page1, {'hashtagTitle': hashtag.substring(1,hashtag.length)});
            });
          },1);
    }
```

Plunker Link - http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5wAVyhOPJNViGdYJ9d5?p=preview

Comment: thanks that works!! SO wont let me upvote your answer since my reputation score is too low..but once its high enough I will.  thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: No problem mate. You can accept the answer if it works fine. And a little more effort you can upvote too .